# How to declare an array and then assign in another line

Tags: c++, arrays

```
class c{};

c *ar[2];

ar = {new c, new c}; //error
```

"Array type is not assignable" 
How to assign it after declaring it, i want to do that because the class is using that variable so i just want to declare it, create a class and then assign the value, i can't assign before the class because it can't make a `new c` without defing the class first.

Comment: You can't *assign* to an array, only copy to it or set its element separately.

Comment: then how do i solve the problem i written about

Comment: Read the last part of my comment again... Or use [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) instead.

Comment: @ViktorLazic I would suggest you to study a good c++ book. SO is not here to baby spoon everyone. Google is your friend.

Comment: Sounds like you could benefit from reading one of [these C++ books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: If the class `c` is using the array, that's probably part of the reason you're stuck. (Also see [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 1):

use standard library algorithm `generate`:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

class c{};
c* ar[2];
std::generate(std::begin(ar), std::end(ar), [] { return new c; });
```

Comment: What was wrong with your previous version using `std::begin` and `std::end`? It's more readable (from begin to end), and less error prone

Comment: @KABoissonneault: https://godbolt.org/g/SFeaBh, GCC 7.1 failed, same `error: no matching function for call to 'begin(c* [2])'` with Clang 4.0, works fine with VS2015 or GCC 4.9, surprised, investigating

Comment: Try including `<iterator>`

Answer (score 0):

use a loop:

```
for(auto i = std::begin(ar);i!=std::end(ar);++i)
    *i = new c;
```

this will work for (almost) all container classes, not just raw arrays.